# What is this pattern of folding and iteration?

Tags: haskell, iteration, fold

Imagine you need to fold over a sequence, and want to know also the intermediate values at several points along the range. This is what I've used for this:

```
[a,b,c] = map fst . tail $ chain [g i, g j, g k] (zero, sequence)

g :: Integer -> (a,b) -> (a,b)

chain (f:fs) x = x : chain fs (f x)
chain [] x = [x]
```

The function `g` consumes a specified portion of an input sequence (of length `i`, `j`, etc.), starting with some initial value and producing results of the same type, to be fed into the next invocation. Consuming the sequence several times for different lengths starting over from the start and same initial value would be inefficient, both time and space-wise of course.

So on the one hand we fold over this sequence of integers - interim points on the sequence; on the other hand we iterate this function, `g`. What is it? Am I missing something basic here? Can this be somehow expressed with the regular repertoire of folds, etc.?

**EDIT:  Resolved:**  the above is simply

```
[a,b,c] = map fst . tail $ scanl (flip g) (zero, sequence) [i, j, k]
```

interesting how a modifiable iteration actually *is* folding over the list of modifiers.

Comment: Do you basically mean scanl? http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=scanl

Comment: @Marcin ah, yes, the basic stuff. Probably yes. What confused me was that `g` itself folds over the sequence as well. I guess the scanning function would combine `(zero,sequence)` with `i` and scan over `[i,j,k]` list directly... Thanks, will try that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `scanl`: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=scanl

> scanl is similar to foldl, but returns a list of successive reduced
>   values from the left:
>
> ```
> scanl f z [x1, x2, ...] == [z, z `f` x1, (z `f` x1) `f` x2, ...]
> ```
>
> Note that
>
> ```
> last (scanl f z xs) == foldl f z xs
> ```

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on Marcin's comment, you basically want:

```
intermediates = scanl step zero sequence
map (\n -> intermediates !! n) [i, j, k]
```

`step` is not `g`, but rather just the part of `g` that consumes a single element of the list `sequence`.

Also, accept Marcin's as the correct answer.

Comment: the sequence itself is huge (well, *big*), and I only need two intermediates and one final. This whole thing is to lower space consumption and give ghc a chance to get rid of as much stuff as possible. Also, I accepted 5 minutes prior to your post. :) Thanks!

Comment: If you compile the above with optimizations GHC should automatically garbage collect intermediate results which you do not use, so it should run in constant space.  It's no more expensive than if you did the intermediate folds yourself by hand.

Comment: I have a suspicion that `(!!n)` will demand the existence of the whole sequence since it must start counting from the start. But I will try it later, thanks. Each previous value is needed to produce the next one; even if it's not needed anymore it's a lot of (gc) activity, and the list itself still will be maintained, so it might not even free each node's value as it was already forced. When calculating by steps that's exactly what's avoided, hopefully. I indeed saw a significant drop in space size with my approach.

Comment: (!! n) only demands the sequence up to the nth value.  You can confirm this by looking at its definition in the Prelude.  scanl depends on all the previous values, but so does foldl.  Where do you think the intermediate values (that you didn't request) computed by foldl go?  They get garbage collected, too.

Comment: last `n` is  very big. `scanl` by chunks will remember three values that I need; `scanl` by steps of 1 will remember all 8500000 of them. :) Unlike foldl, scanl expicitly requests to store all the interim results, and I only need three of those.

Comment: Well, in Haskell there is no such thing as explicitly requesting to store results.  If a results are not used, it is garbage collected, all 8500000 of them.  Usually the only time the entire list is accumulated in memory is if GHC misses a fusion opportunity to prevent the creation of intermediate data structures.  To learn more about this, check out http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html, specifically the "List fusion" section.

Comment: but you access the `intermediates` list three times, starting over. So the list will stay in existence for at least two accesses. It is true that normally accessing the i-th elt by itself shouldn't force others but here it does. I believe that forced values residing in a list's nodes will only get gc-ed when the list itself will. GHC should be *extremely* smart and *bold* to leave dangling pointers there. Or it should look ahead into `[i,j,k]`, see that `i<j<k` and calculate and use the differences instead of starting over. Supremely unlikely optimization. But I'll try it. I'll need 1day or2.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  Unless i, j, and k are formulated as peano natural numbers then it is incredibly unlikely that GHC will cache the result from the lowest value first and use it to calculate the remainders.  However, you could easily implement the optimization yourself by dropping i elements from the list generated by scanl, then j-i elements, then k-j elements (assuming [i, j, k] is sorted)

Comment: I've tried your last suggestion and it gives me stack space overflow pretty fast, also shooting up memory usage. I used `[a,b,c] = map head . tail $ scanl (flip (drop.fromInteger)) vals [i,j,k]` where `vals = scanl g1 zero sequence` and `g1 :: a -> e -> a; sequence :: [e]` (referring to `i,j,k` in my question, which were differences in the first place).

Comment: I've added strictness annotations to `scanl` to make a `scanl'` out of it, and eta-expanded `flip drop` with strictness annotations as well. Now there's no stack overflow but the memory usage is very high, so much so that the execution doesn't finish, and I have to kill the process. Adding bang patterns to `drop` doesn't help either.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suppose it does not optimize as well as I thought.